# Why my Angular routing treats domain url parts as segment?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Lets say I have domain like: **http://some_domain_part1/some_domain_part2/some_domain_part3/**

When I'm running my app on such domain I'm getting error: `Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'some_domain_part2/some_domain_part3/'`. After that I'm redirecting to the same URL and all works fine. It happens only when I open new tab in my browser with my app. When I just refresh the browser tab all work fine. What might be the reason of such error?

Comment: Which webserver are you using?

Comment: I use chrome but it occurs on all browsers

Comment: Chrome is a browser. A webserver is like apache, nginx, iis, tomcat...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Put .htaccess file at srever.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .* index.html [L]
```